# keyup not working on dynamically loaded textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, textarea, keyup

Other event types seem to work fine here - for example, `mouseenter`:

```
$("body").delegate(".textareas", "mouseenter", myalert);
```

But using `keyup`, or `keypress` - it wont work. I didn't change anything else in my code except the event type on this line. Example:

```
$("body").delegate(".textareas", "keyup", myalert);
```

I type in a textarea, but now `myalert` doesn't get called.

I'm using jquery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified` does more than I need for this, but at least it seems to notice any entered text too, so if anyone else runs into this same problem, that's what's sort of working for me until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an on to bind

http://jsfiddle.net/Jy2rA/

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('body').append('<textarea>');
});

$('body').on('keyup', 'textarea', function() {
    $('p').fadeIn(function(){$(this).fadeOut()});
});​
```